# using Dll in WinForm

Tags: winforms, dll

I am trying to use DLL NI4882 in winForm.
There is namespace in dll "NationalInstruments.NI4882.Internal;" where a class exists "GpidDll" which is internal and sealed class.

> This is the code snippet of class "GpidDll" in NI4882 DLL

```
 [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal sealed class GpibDll
    {
       [DllImport("ni4882.dll", EntryPoint="ibfind",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       private static extern IntPtr _ibfind(string udname);


       public static GpibHandle ibfind(string udname);
    }
```

Now I want to call ibfind from winform. But I am getting error of **"Unable to find an entry point"** when I use

> [DllImport(@"C:\Project\NationalInstruments.NI4882.dll", 
>   EntryPoint="ibfind",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
>
> private static extern IntPtr _ibfind(string udname);

**calling function**

```
public void ibfind_Ext(string udname, ref IntPtr ud)
{
    ud = _ibfind(udname);
}
```

I also think of other option like creating object of GpidDll and then calling ibfind but I can't to that because of access specifier(Internal) as my project is in different namespace.

Comment: The declaration does not look correct.  There ought to be two entrypoints, ibfindA and ibfindW.  The CharSet property selects which one is getting used, EntryPoint defeats it.  Use Dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to verify names.

Comment: Is it possible to call function of such dll whose class are sealed and internal and functions are private?

Comment: This is a DLL that contains native code, words like class, sealed, internal, private just don't mean anything to such a DLL.  If you have no idea how to do this correctly and don't know how to use Dumpbin.exe then be sure to call NI for support.

Comment: I have asked NI support for help but received no reply yet